Is it possible to have python workers use different global context?
We have a singleton object we use for our program that refers to an ugly god-object that I wish would die - we inherited the code from a team that had already implemented it this way.  Unfortunately stripping the singleton out is a non-trivial task at this point.
We want to have a rest endpoint, using django rest_framework to be exact, which is using a partially initialized version of our main program to, with just enough set up to answer questions about how our main program would respond to certain inputs.
The problem is that the singleton object has state that would need to be different for each incoming request, but right now since it's a global variable changing it in one worker changes it in all workers which would risk datarace issues if we have two commands that need different state come in at the same time and running on separate threads.
I'm wondering if there is a way to set up workers to have their own version of global variables and our singleton which aren't affected by changes to the singleton in other workers so we can change state in a worker without worrying about it affecting other rest calls; short of spinning up a new subprocess each time?

Yes, workers use a copy/snapshot of the "singleton" instead the the global one.

okay, but how do I inject it?  I can't swap it and then spin up the worker or I'd risk a datarace
